# Newbie inserting into binary tree checks

Tags: python, insert, binary-search-tree

I am learning about Binary Search trees and I don't understand why this code won't work for insert in to a binary search tree:

```
def insert(self, data, node):
    node_to_insert = Node(data)

    if node is None:
        node = node_to_insert
    else:
        if data < node.data:
            node.left = self.insert(data, node.left)
        else:
            node.right = self.insert(data, node.right)
```

I know this code works:

```
    def insert(self, data, node):
        node_to_insert = Node(data)

        if node is None:
            node = node_to_insert
        else:
            if data < node.data:
                if node.left is None:
                    node.left = node_to_insert
                else:
                    self.insert(data, node.left)
            else:
                if node.right is None:
                    node.right = node_to_insert
                else:
                    self.insert(data, node.right)
```

The way I see it is that the extra `is None` check should be done when the function is recalled no?

Also why does this work:

```
def print_inorder(self, node):
    if node is not None:
        self.print_inorder(node.left)
        print node.data
        self.print_inorder(node.right)
```

when it doesnt have the extra checks to see if `node.left is None` before calling `self.print_inorder(node.left)`

Comment: when you say something doesn't work, can you be more specific?  does it error (and please copy/paste is the error) or does it return an unexpected result (and please copy/paste the result)...thanks!

Comment: Neither insertion function works. The first one fails because it never returns anything to assign to `node.left` or `node.right`, but the second one still fails for insertion into an empty tree. [Read up on the `return` statement.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/why-would-you-use-the-return-statement-in-python)

Comment: please don't use TABS for indenting (instead use 4 spaces) and read about pep8 before it's too late...

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
if data < node.data:
    node.left = self.insert(data, node.left)
else:
    node.right = self.insert(data, node.right)
```

Your method `self.insert` returns `None`, so after the data is properly inserted into `node.left` or `node.right`, you are assigning `None` to them. Rather you want

```
if data < node.data:
    self.insert(data, node.left)
else:
    self.insert(data, node.right)
```